# Amazon cognito php documentation not full

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to use amazon congnito to my php backend, I find this first understandable example [here](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1YVAQ4NZKBWF5/Amazon-Cognito-Announcing-Developer-Authenticated-Identities) .

Firstly I try to find class  GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest in [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-cognitoidentity.html) but I can't find this class in php documentation. Is anybody use this service in PHP , could you help me?

Comment: [Amazon Cognito Identity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-cognitoidentity.html)

Answer (score 1):

the PHP SDK has been updated to support developer authenticated identities. You can review the updated docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.CognitoIdentity.CognitoIdentityClient.html#_getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity).

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question in amazon forum, answer is:

> Hello:
>
> Unfortunately, the PHP SDK has not been updated to supported developer
>   authenticated identities. I've contacted the team that is responsible
>   for the SDK and we'll update you as soon as this support is available.
>
> Regards, Bob